# Recovery partition in the middle of the file system

Tags: partition

I have a problem with my recovery partition. Before update to the el-capitan I had both osx and windows on the same ssd disc created with Boot Camp. The problem is that something went wrong during the upgrade to el-capitan, and I decided to remove the windows partition through Boot Camp. My disc has 250 GB, but for my system is available only 180GB, and I'm not able to find how I can extend the size of my partition. Below I'm attaching the screen from Disc Utility.

[image: DIsc Utility]

Do you know how can I use my free disc space? Probably I have to move my Recovery partition to the end of my disc, but I'm not so sure about that.

And here is the print screen from `diskutil list` command:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To fix:

- Boot into the OS as normal.
- Open a terminal and type: `diskutil list`
- Repair the disk: `diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk0s3` (where disk0s3 is your recovery disk)
- Verify the disk: `diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s3`
- Resize the partition: `sudo diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s3 650M` (and enter your Mac passcode)

If successful, restart your Mac and after open disk utility and resize your core partition. Done.

Comment: nope, still not possible to change the main partition. The Strange thing is that I have 2 Recovery partition, I uploaded the print screen in the main question

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and resolved by using Disk Utility that was on an external drive with Sierra installed.

Hope that helps

Mark

Comment: How exactly did you use Disk Utility to solve this problem?